# Android Device Restart after exactly 12:42:xx Hours

Tags: freeze, restart, reboot

I'm observing a significant amount of cases of freezing DELL streak devices (Android 2.2).

The whole device (not only the application) freezes (even power off button does not work) and exactly after 12 hours 42 minutes and a few seconds around 30 the devices reboots automatically and is fully functional again.

I searched around to find anything about this exact time and a possible reason for the freeze and restart, but nothing.

Does anybody have an idea or have seen this exact time in any content?

Kind regards

Comment: there might be some Remote Reboot function which just takes place, like once a day on all frozen Dell Streaks. just wild thinking... :D

Comment: Well, my guess is that something freezes the device and there is a checking mechanism which restarts the device automatically. Would love to find the reason why the devices are freezing, and maybe 12 hours 42 minutes is a number somebody have heart before.

Comment: it can be anything, and i thought of it, but then why would it check and restart after 12 hours when it should just do it immediately. :P. but it can be anything. :D

Comment: jeah, that's a good question. and why should it restart exactly after 12 hours and 42 MINUTES and not just 12 hours ;-) Seems to be something by purpose